# xamdatagrid Disable column conditionally

Tags: wpf, mvvm, xamdatagrid

I have a requirement of disabling a perticular cell in a row, depending on values in other cells of the same row.

WPF or WPF MVVM scenarios, both solutions are welcome.

I tried both and none works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Grenter.
I did solve it by implementing Converter class and implementing it as a static resource in my xaml file.
Also, I figured out that we can do the same using the cell updating or cell updated event and writing some lines of code in the xaml code behind, which I generally donot prefer.

But converters is certainly the way to go forward.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly.

You might want to take a look at DataGridTemplateColumn within the Datagrid.Columns section (see Code Below) as this allows you to set up your own templates for the column/cell and then you can set the enabled property. The following is only a simple solution and going forward I would have it so that when you change the enable checkbox that updates the model which in turn would enable the items in the row.

```
        <DataGrid Name="dgrgrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">                
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price"  />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Row Enabled" Binding="{Binding Enabled}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

for the code behind I have a simple observable collection of a class called Cheese which has some properties that you see below. (This is basic M-V-VM technique)

Comment: Oh and one more things I missed out is that you can do binding to other columns or values for the same row and then use a converter (see link below) to convert from a string value to a Visibility or a true false thus allowing you to disable columns based on the values in the column next to it. http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html